# htaccess RewriteRule for URL with parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there are many questions concerning this topic already, but although searching quite a while I couldn't find a solution for my problem:

**I want to redirect this url:**
http://www.website.com/website/wp/?lang=sla
and this url:
http://www.website.com/website/wp?lang=sla
(same but without trailing slash)

**to:**
http://www.website.com/sk/

I've tried this already, but it seems to be ignored:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=de$
RewriteRule ^website/wp/$ /de/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Looks good to me, except `lang` parameter, of course. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work, always redirects to http://www.website.com/?lang=de
So it ignores the new directory, redirects to root, but keeps the parameter.

(lang value must not be automatically used as directory, as it also can be different values)